# Bluetooth door locks

Tags: bluetooth

Can somebody patent a lock to be opened by wireless method?  I would assume not, but it seems like there are a lot of companies that claim they have patented this technology to open the lock.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would think this was a subject area that was immune to patents. There are dozens of issued U.S. patents involving wireless control of locks. Each has its own twist. One of them is:

> Deadbolt lock
>   US 7963134 B2
>
> Master Lock
>
> ABSTRACT
>
> A deadbolt lock includes a deadbolt, a user rotatable actuator, and a lock interface. The user rotatable actuator is operatively connected with the deadbolt for movement of the deadbolt between locked and unlocked conditions when the actuator is changed from an inoperable condition to an operable condition. The lock interface is configured to change the actuator from the inoperable condition to the operable condition in response to proper user manipulation of the lock interface.